# Unexpected result from code of array_diff_assoc documentation

Tags: php, arrays

Here is an example from [PHP documentation about `array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php#example-6085).

> In this example you see the `"a" => "green"` pair is present in both arrays and thus it is not in the output from the function. Unlike this, the pair `0 => "red"` is in the output because in the second argument `"red"` has key which is `1`.
>
> ```
> <?php
> $array1 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "red");
> $array2 = array("a" => "green", "yellow", "red");
> $result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
> print_r($result);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [b] => brown
>     [c] => blue
>     [0] => red
> )
> ```

`red` is present in both arrays, but it is returned in the output of `array_diff_assoc`, why PHP *think* that `red` in `$array1` and `$array2` is different?

Comment: compares array1 against array2 and returns the difference. Unlike array_diff() the array keys are also used in the comparison. And the key for `red` in the first array is `0` but in the second it is `1`

Comment: If you `print_r()` array 1 and 2, you will see that the index/key of 'red' is different, this is significant in `array_diff_assoc()` which is different to the way `array_diff()` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because in the first array the index of red is 0 and in the second array the index of red is 1 so they are different.

[`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

From the docs:

> Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check

[Check the vardumps](https://3v4l.org/qamPW):

```
<?php

$array1 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("a" => "green", "yellow", "red");
var_dump($array1);
var_dump($array2);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(5) "green"
  ["b"]=>
  string(5) "brown"
  ["c"]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  [0]=>
  string(3) "red"
}
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(5) "green"
  [0]=>
  string(6) "yellow"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "red"
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that PHP added keys to values that don't have keys. Thanks.

Comment: You could read about keys on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). `The key is optional. If it is not specified, PHP will use the increment of the largest previously used integer key.`

Answer (score 1):

The key for red in $array1 is 0:

$array1
( [a] => green [b] => brown [c] => blue **[0]** => red )

$array2
( [a] => green [0] => yellow **[1]** => red )